# How to copy built DLL from one SUBDIR to another?

Tags: qt, qmake, qt6

I have following project architecture

```
project.pro
|
|--app.pro
|
|--lib1.pro
|
|--lib2.pro
```

`lib1` is a shared library. `lib2` depends on `lib1`.

`app` depends on `lib1` and `lib2`

```
project.pro:

SUBDIRS = \
         app \
         lib1 \
         lib2 \

# Introduce sub projects
app.subdir = src/app
lib1.subdir = src/core/lib1
lib2.subdir = src/core/lib2

# Make app dependent from lib1 and lib2
# This way lib1 and lib2 get build first
lib2.depends = lib1
app.depends = lib1 lib2
```

Now, `lib1` builds fine. But `lib1.pro` is unable to copy `lib1.dll` to `lib2 folder`. I tried being proactive in `lib1.pro` and create `lib2 folder` and copy the dll. And vise versa. The ways for copying I tried are

`CONFIG += file_copies`,

`INSTALLS +=...` (I added make install as additional build step in QtCreator)

`QMAKE_POST_LINK` with the correct copy cmd

I even checked with qmake `exists()` if `lib1.dll` is created before trying to copy it. The file is created every time.

Anyone has an idea? Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
lib1.pro

TARGET = lib1
TEMPLATE = lib
DESTDIR = $$OUT_PWD/../bin
```

```
lib2.pro

INCLUDEPATH += $$OUT_PWD/../bin
LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../bin -llib1
```